# Renaming CAN interfaces

Tags: networking, udev

I have a system with multiple CAN devices that we are using to control other devices in an automation environment and I would like to give them persistent names to help with debugging and configuration. I've been trying to get this to work using udev, and only having partial success.

We are using IXXAT USB to CAN v2 devices, although I have the same problems with other socketcan devices (also tried on a kvasser dongle)

The UDev tree for the device looks like this, omitting the standard usb/pci parts:

```
  looking at device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-1/1-1:1.0/net/can0':
    KERNEL=="can0"
    SUBSYSTEM=="net"
    DRIVER==""
    ATTR{mtu}=="16"
    ATTR{type}=="280"
    ATTR{netdev_group}=="0"
    ATTR{flags}=="0x40081"
    ATTR{dormant}=="0"
    ATTR{proto_down}=="0"
    ATTR{addr_assign_type}=="0"
    ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0"
    ATTR{gro_flush_timeout}=="0"
    ATTR{iflink}=="6"
    ATTR{addr_len}=="0"
    ATTR{address}==""
    ATTR{operstate}=="unknown"
    ATTR{carrier_changes}=="0"
    ATTR{broadcast}==""
    ATTR{tx_queue_len}=="10"
    ATTR{dev_port}=="0"
    ATTR{ifalias}==""
    ATTR{ifindex}=="6"
    ATTR{link_mode}=="0"
    ATTR{carrier}=="1"

  looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-1/1-1:1.0':
    KERNELS=="1-1:1.0"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="usb"
    DRIVERS=="ixx_usb"
    ATTRS{bInterfaceClass}=="ff"
    ATTRS{bInterfaceSubClass}=="ff"
    ATTRS{bInterfaceProtocol}=="ff"
    ATTRS{bNumEndpoints}=="0a"
    ATTRS{authorized}=="1"
    ATTRS{supports_autosuspend}=="0"
    ATTRS{bAlternateSetting}==" 0"
    ATTRS{bInterfaceNumber}=="00"

  looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-1':
    KERNELS=="1-1"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="usb"
    DRIVERS=="usb"
    ATTRS{bDeviceSubClass}=="00"
    ATTRS{bDeviceProtocol}=="ff"
    ATTRS{devpath}=="1"
    ATTRS{idVendor}=="08d8"
    ATTRS{speed}=="480"
    ATTRS{bNumInterfaces}==" 1"
    ATTRS{bConfigurationValue}=="1"
    ATTRS{bMaxPacketSize0}=="64"
    ATTRS{busnum}=="1"
    ATTRS{devnum}=="7"
    ATTRS{configuration}==""
    ATTRS{bMaxPower}=="300mA"
    ATTRS{authorized}=="1"
    ATTRS{bmAttributes}=="a0"
    ATTRS{bNumConfigurations}=="2"
    ATTRS{maxchild}=="0"
    ATTRS{bcdDevice}=="0100"
    ATTRS{avoid_reset_quirk}=="0"
    ATTRS{quirks}=="0x0"
    ATTRS{serial}=="HW486964"
    ATTRS{version}==" 2.00"
    ATTRS{urbnum}=="31"
    ATTRS{ltm_capable}=="no"
    ATTRS{manufacturer}=="IXXAT"
    ATTRS{removable}=="removable"
    ATTRS{idProduct}=="0008"
    ATTRS{bDeviceClass}=="00"
    ATTRS{product}=="USB-to-CAN V2"
```

The UDEV rule I'm trying to implement is this:

```
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ATTRS{idVendor}=="08d8", ATTRS{idProduct}=="0008", ATTRS{serial}=="HW486964", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", NAME="canTest"
```

Which monitoring when the device is plugged in:

```
KERNEL[9271.146978] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-1 (usb)
KERNEL[9271.148311] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-1/1-1:1.0 (usb)
KERNEL[9271.653719] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-1/1-1:1.0/net/can0 (net)
KERNEL[9271.654067] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-1/1-1:1.0/net/can0/queues/rx-0 (queues)
KERNEL[9271.654154] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-1/1-1:1.0/net/can0/queues/tx-0 (queues)
UDEV  [9271.674443] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-1 (usb)
UDEV  [9271.677002] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-1/1-1:1.0 (usb)
KERNEL[9271.678372] move     /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-1/1-1:1.0/net/canTest (net)
UDEV  [9271.694467] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-1/1-1:1.0/net/canTest (net)
UDEV  [9271.696129] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-1/1-1:1.0/net/can0/queues/rx-0 (queues)
UDEV  [9271.698886] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-1/1-1:1.0/net/can0/queues/tx-0 (queues)
UDEV  [9271.700647] move     /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-1/1-1:1.0/net/canTest (net)
```

We can see that it moves the device, but it won't bring up the interface and ifup/down will not see it by either name. The ip command can see the device by name **canTest**, but will not bring up the interface.

I can give the device a different name if I know the kernel identifier for it when it is plugged in and removing the custom rename rule by using the ip utility.

```
sudo ip link set canX down
sudo ip link set canX name canTest
sudo ip link set canTest up
```

Other info
OS(s): Ubuntu (14.04, 16.04, 18.04)
Kernel(s): 3.13.0, 4.4.0, 4.15.0

Comment: Did you find a solution that works for you?

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with systemd-networkd.

First create these two files in `/etc/systemd/network/`

```bash
### /etc/systemd/network/49-cantest.link
[Match]
Property=ID_SERIAL_SHORT=004B003F4733570620353439
[Link]
Name=canTest
```

see: [help for `Property=`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.network.html#Property=)

```bash
### /etc/systemd/network/50-cantest.network
[Match]
Name=canTest
[CAN]
BitRate=500000
```

Next, reboot. The `canTest` interface should appear.

```bash
> ip link
...
4: canTest: <NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP,ECHO> mtu 16 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 10
    link/can
...
```

In the above answer I used the `ID_SERIAL_SHORT` property to uniquely identify my CAN adapter. You can find additional properties associated with your CAN adapter with the following command

```bash
udevadm info -p $(udevadm info --query=path --path=/sys/class/net/can0)
```

related source:
https://www.pengutronix.de/en/blog/2022-02-04-initializing-can-interfaces-with-systemd-networkd.html